# InMobi Ad integration in Android

Tags: android, inmobi

I'm working on `InMobi` Ad integration with sample project.

I've updated the `project id` and `PLACEMENT_ID` but I'm getting below message on **`onAdLoadFailed`**

```
Unable to load interstitial ad (error message: An invalid ad request was sent and was rejected by the Ad Network. Please validate the ad request and try again)
```

Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, in my case i was using device ID except advertising id of device while adding devices for test in Inmobi. and in Inmobi they change key in response Json with every version of SDK (ie its one for 5.0.0 and different for 5.0.1).

Comment: @Javi Rueda I am also facing the same issue, I could not understood your solution, can you please explain how you got rid of this issue?

Comment: @IshantSagar you need to add a device in InMobi panel with advertising id of device for testing, and also switch on the test mode.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem. Using SDK 5.0.0 integrating Native Ads.

In test mode, slot requested is "0", and it shows no problem, although no ad is filled. When disabling Test Mode, the error @Ankit says is appearing in LogCat.

I have another application which integrates InMobi, but Interstitial ones. It is ansewering request with error and, when it works- some hours ago- it just fills a blank -transparent- ad.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, can ypu tell me if you found any solutions, or any update on the issue..

Comment: @RajatSinghal I just have fixed it. The problem I had was not keeping classes of Play Services on Proguard. See https://www.inmobi.com/support/integration/23817448/22051163/android-sdk-integration-guide/